# Want to change div dynamically when clicking link in sidebar with JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am working on a recipes page and I have code that currently grabs JSON data and displays it in respective div's on the page. I want to achieve code re usability and to be able to dynamically change contents based on the link in the sidebar and have it grab to the correct JSON data and update the divs on the page. Currently my data only takes one recipe from the JSON database and displays it on the page. I want to avoid making multiple pages and duplication the JS for each recipe.

Snippet is below:

```js
(function() {

  'use strict';

  var url = '';

 // $.getJSON(url, function(json) {

 var json =     [  
        [
            {
       "id":"1",
                "category":"pasta",
                "seasonal":"fall",
                "recipeName":"Bolognese Sauce",
                "prepTime":"20 Min",
                "cookTime":"30 Min",
                "servInfo":"4-6",
                "directions":"lorem ipsum",
                "ingredients":[
                    "1 lb Rigatoni",
                    "3 tbsp Extra Virgin Olive Oil, plus extra for drizzling",
                    "1 cup white onions, diced",
                    "¼ cup carrots, diced",
                    "¼ cup celery, diced",
                    "1 ½ lb. ground beef",
                    "¼ cup Tomato Paste in a Tube",
                    "1 1/2 cup All Purpose Beef Broth",
                    "½ cup heavy cream",
                    "1 Bay Leaf",
                    "1 can Certified San Marzano Tomatoes (28 oz), crushed by hand",
                    "1 can All Purpose Crushed Tomatoes (28 oz)",
                    "¼ cup fresh basil, chopped",
                    "Salt and Ground Black Pepper, to taste"
                ],
                "imageURL":"path",
       "href": "path"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
       "id":"2",
                "category":"pizza",
                "seasonal":"winter",
                "recipeName":"Arugula Pizza",
                "prepTime":"30 Min",
                "cookTime":"10 Min",
                "servInfo":"3-4",
                "directions":"lorem ipsum",
                "ingredients":[
                    "4 lb Rigatoni",
                    "3 tbsp Extra Virgin Olive Oil, plus extra for drizzling",
                    "1 cup white onions, diced",
                    "¼ cup carrots, diced",
                    "¼ cup celery, diced",
                    "1 ½ lb. ground beef",
                    "¼ cup Tomato Paste in a Tube",
                    "1 1/2 cup All Purpose Beef Broth",
                    "½ cup heavy cream",
                    "1 Bay Leaf",
                    "1 can Certified San Marzano Tomatoes (28 oz), crushed by hand",
                    "1 can All Purpose Crushed Tomatoes (28 oz)",
                    "¼ cup fresh basil, chopped",
                    "Salt and Ground Black Pepper, to taste"
                ],
                "imageURL":"path",
       "href": "path"
            }
        ]
    ];
  
    var title = '';
    var image = '';
    var directions = '';
    var prep = '';
    var cook = '';
    var serve = '';

    $.each(json[0], function(i, item) {
      title += '<h1>' + item.recipeName + '</h1>';
      image += '<img class="imgJSONheader" src="' + item.imageURL + '">';
      directions += '<p>' + item.directions + '</p>';
      prep += '<strong>' + item.prepTime + '</strong>';
      cook += '<strong>' + item.cookTime + '</strong>';
      serve += '<strong>' + item.servInfo + '</strong>';
    });

    $('#recipeTitle').html(title);
    $('#recipeImagesHeader').html(image);
    $('#recipeDirections').html(directions);
    $('#recipePrep').html(prep);
    $('#recipeCook').html(cook);
    $('#recipeServes').html(serve);

    var ul = $('<ul class="nav nav-stacked">').appendTo('#recipeIngredients');

    $.each(json[0][0].ingredients, function(i, item) {
      ul.append($(document.createElement('li')).text(item));
    });

    var images = '';

    var collection = [];

    $.each(json, function(i, item) {
      if ($.inArray(item[0].category, collection) === -1) {
        collection.push(item[0].category);
        images += '<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">' + '<a href="' + (item[0].href) + '">' + '<img class="img img-responsive img-hover imgJSONCategory" src="' + (item[0].imageURL) + '">' + '</a>' + '<h1>' + (item[0].category) + '</h1>' + '</div>';
      }
    });

    $('#imagesCategory').html(images);

//  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Test Header Start -->
<section>
  <div class="carousel fade-carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="4000" id="bs-carousel">
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item slides active">
        <div id="recipeImagesHeader"></div>
        <div class="hero">
          <hgroup>
            <h1>Sauces</h1> 
          </hgroup>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- Test Header End -->

<!-- Test Recipe Sidebar Container -->
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- Sidebar Start -->
      <div class="col-md-3 visible-lg visible-md">
        <ul class="nav nav-stacked" id="sidebar">
          <li class="sidebarLink"><a href="">Seasonal</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Breakfast</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Pasta</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sauces</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Appetizers</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- Main Section Start -->
      <div class="col-md-9" id="mainCol">
        <div class="row" id="mainHeader">
          <!-- Title Start -->
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div id="recipeTitle"></div>
          </div>
          <!-- Prep, Cook, Serves Start -->
          <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                <h4>Prep Time</h4><span id="recipePrep"></span>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                <h4>Cook Time</h4><span id="recipeCook"></span>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                <h4>Serves</h4><span id="recipeServes"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <!-- Ingredients Start -->
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <h2>Ingredients</h2>
            <div id="recipeIngredients"></div>
          </div>
          <!-- Directions Start -->
          <div class="col-md-7">
            <h2>Directions</h2>
            <div id="recipeDirections"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- /.row -->
```

Comment: they are all in an external JSON file I will post the JSON at the top now

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well so we can see what things like `#recipeTitle` are?

Comment: sure posting this now thank you

Comment: Better yet, make a fiddle (the code is nicely-formatted but is getting a little long to read): https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: made on at the top thx

Comment: I updated your snippet to include the data, but not the ajax call. It's a bit unclear as to where the links are that are supposed to correspond to the recipe you want to show, however.

Comment: I just want to make it so say I click the link on the sidebar that says (seasonal) to show certain data that pertains to it. That would be recipes that fall under seasonal. But in the example of my JSON file (very basic for testing). I just have a pizza and pasta recipe. If i have a link on the sidebar that corresponsed to the correct recipe, Id want it to show on the page. I havent gotten that far yet thats why my code is not very developed but I am not sure how to do an AJAX call on something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried wrapping your initial loop in a loop.

```
 $.each(json, function(idx, json_item) { 
     $.each(json_item, function (i, item) {
         title += '<h1>' + item.recipeName + '</h1>';
         image += '<img class="imgJSONheader" src="' + item.imageURL + '">';
         directions += '<p>' + item.directions + '</p>';
         prep += '<strong>' + item.prepTime + '</strong>';
         cook += '<strong>' + item.cookTime + '</strong>';
         serve += '<strong>' + item.servInfo + '</strong>';
     });
)};
```

Link to [codepen](http://codepen.io/mattchewone/pen/BLOXEX?editors=1010)

Comment: i havent but that wouldnt make it change upon click right?

Comment: Sorry not sure I understand what you mean. It looks like your code only loops through the first object in the JSON and the code in my initial reply would loop over the whole JSON file.

Comment: Yes your correct. Thats essentially what I need to do and I need to filter the results based on the recipe clicked that corresponds to the link (name of recipe) on the sidebar

Comment: except im not sure what i need to do to achieve that

Comment: So you want to hide the list and only have visible the selected recipe? Or are no recipes shown until one from the side bar is selected? I think I may have misunderstood.

Comment: yep exactly. i dont want to show any recipes until one is picked from the sidebar. i need to hide the recipe and show the correct one based on the link thats clicked in the sidebar that corresponds with the recipes names. then the page will automatically refresh showing all the recipes data

Comment: I put together bits of your code on codepen - `http://codepen.io/mattchewone/pen/BLOXEX?editors=1010` let me know whether this is more of what you are aiming for. It's just a rough idea on what I think you are looking for.

Comment: thats it!! thank you!! i had no idea how to acheive this but now I see how it can be done. thank you soo much =)

Comment: No problem at all. Like I say just a rough idea to get the idea across. Best of luck